# why <jvmarg value="-version"/> will disable the print out

Tags: java, ant

I  have a very simple main method to print out the parameter passed in.
If I run the program with **"ant run"** by passing "**this**" and "**that**". The print out will like this:

```
run:
     [java] Hello updatetool.
     [java] Started with these parameters:  
     [java] 1. backup location, absolute path:this  
     [java] 2. new install location, absolute path:that

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Then I add the "-version" jvm parameter like this:

```
<target name="run" depends="echo" 
        description="Run application from development environment">
        <java classname="${program.main}"
              classpathref="compile.classpath"
              fork="true">
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx${MAX_MEMORY}m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xms${MIN_MEMORY}m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-XX:NewSize=${YOUNG_MEMORY}m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-version"/>  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<***************+++++++++
            <arg value="this"/>
            <arg value="that"/>
         </java>
    </target>
```

But the program output changed like this:

```
run:
     [java] java version "1.7.0_06"
     [java] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_06-b24)
     [java] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

There is no print out for "**this**" and "**that**". There is no other changes on my Java file.

Why?

I am running on a linux machine.

Here is my main method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello updatetool.");
        int numOfParameters = 2;

        if(args == null || args.length < numOfParameters)
        {
            System.out.println("Not enough parameters. Usage of this tool:"
                    + "\t\n1. backup location, absolute path;"
                    + "\t\n2. new install location, absolute path;"
                    );
            System.exit(1);

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Started with these parameters:"
                    + "\t\n1. backup location, absolute path:" + args[0]
                    + "\t\n2. new install location, absolute path:" + args[1]
                    );
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-version` makes the Java launcher print out its version information and exit. The rest of the command line is ignored.

You can find the descriptions of the accepted command line options [for Windows here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) and [for Unix here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html)